# Сгруппировать временные интервалы

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.
Есть таблица, в которой одна из колонок содержит некую дату.
Требуется разбить данные на временные интервалы (по дате по возрастанию). Если между ближайшими датами менее 10 минут, то это один интервал. Если между датами более 10 минут, то начинается новый интервал.
Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (DateOfAdded DATETIME2(0));
INSERT #temp (DateOfAdded) VALUES
('2017-11-26 13:21:13'),
('2017-11-26 13:21:18'),
('2017-11-26 13:22:22'),
('2017-11-26 13:23:58'),
('2017-11-26 13:38:47'),
('2017-11-26 13:39:13'),
('2017-11-26 13:53:33'),
('2017-11-26 13:53:42'),
('2017-11-26 13:54:54');
```

Ожидаю, чтобы получилось как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видится, что смогу проставить номер интервала курсором. Но через курсор не очень хочется.

SQL server 2016

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *,
       sum(mark) over(order by DateOfAdded)
  from (
    select *,
           case when datediff(minute,
                              lag(DateOfAdded) over(order by DateOfAdded),
                              DateOfAdded)>10
           then 1 else 0 end mark
      from #temp
  ) x
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.